# Could my iPad app be denied from the app store for using the Tapku library?

Tags: iphone, ipad, calendar, appstore-approval

I'd like to use the [Tapku library](http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary) to add a calander date picker control to my iPad app.  I'm new to iPhone OS development and I'm still rusty on identifying the 3rd party tools and code that will get my iPad app denied from the app store.  For those that have used the Tapku library, would using it in my iPad app violate any app store rules?

Thanks so much in advance for your help.  I'm going to continue researching this question right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have any trouble using a 3rd party framework.  There's a whole lot of speculation going around about what's in and out, but from what I've read frameworks are not included in the license change.

> Applications must be originally written in Objective-C, C, C++, or JavaScript as executed by the iPhone OS WebKit engine, and only code written in C, C++, and Objective-C may compile and directly link against the Documented APIs (e.g., Applications that link to Documented APIs through an intermediary translation or compatibility layer or tool are prohibited)

Tapku (as far as I know) is written in Objective-C, so I don't see a violation of the above.  The modifications to the agreement mostly address frameworks like [Adobe's iPhone Packager](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashcs5/appsfor_iphone/) and [Monotouch](http://monotouch.net/).

On another note - don't worry too much about whether your app will get rejected or not.  Read the [iPhone Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and use their standard API and you'll do fine.  If you do get rejected they will normally give you a detailed explanation why.

Comment: Yes Gavin is correct Tapku is Objective-C and written with xcode and is safe now and in the future as being a valid 3rd party library from a code point of view.  The only thing left to consider is to make sure that Tapku is not doing anything within its library that would violate the Apple agreement.  Since the library was designed for use with Cocoa Touch it is most likely safe.

Comment: Thanks so much, Gavin and Creepy, I'll continue looking into this.

Comment: This section only applies to 4.0. (IANAL)